# Center a button and textView

Tags: java, android, center

Can someone help me to figure out my problem? At the last row of my table, I have a button and I want it to be centered. Below is the coding snippet.

```
<TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

1. Why doesn't the coding work?
2. How to put a textView beside the button?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TableRow
 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"   
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_gravity="center" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"   
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>

   <TextView 
    ...
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    ...
    />

 </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android:layout_span="max__number_of_columns"` to make the RelativeLayout width match parent.
Inside RelativeLayout you can put Button in center and Textview beside button easy.
Try this code

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2" // 2 is the number of col in your table
         >
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="button" />
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaa"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button"
         />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This LinearLayout layout or its TableRow parent is possibly useless

Just Try like:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<TableRow>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```